# mysql in python encoding

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, mysql-python

This post is the same with my question in [MySQL in Python: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330046/mysql-in-python-unicodeencodeerror-ascii) this is just to clear things up.

I am trying to save a string to a MySQL database but I get an error:

> File ".smart.py", line 51, in 
>        (number, text, 'smart', 'u')
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position
>   25: ordinal not in range(128)

and the string is saved at ***m['Text']***

> Lala*=#&%@<>_?!:;-'"/()¥¡¿

Here is a snippet to the code

```
risk = m['Text']
msg = risk.encode('utf8')
text = db.escape_string(msg)

sql = "INSERT INTO posts(nmbr, \
       msg, tel, sts) \
       VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % \
       (number, text, 'smart', 'u')
```

If i try to comment out the SQL query and put ***print text*** it would print out Lala*=#&%@<>_?!:;-'"/()¥¡¿

The error is only encountered when the SQL is being processed.

MySQL encoding is set to utf8_unicode_ci. (or should i change this?)

Thanks.

Comment: i get the error stated above. I get an encoding error i think.

Comment: if i only do
risk = m['Text']
msg = risk.encode('utf8')
text = db.escape_string(msg)
print text
everything works fine.

Comment: are you using MySQLdb, if so what is your connection string??

Comment: db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root","password","application")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add these parameters `MySQLdb.connect(..., use_unicode=1,charset="utf8")`.

create a cursor

```
cur = db.cursor()
```

and then execute like so:

```
risk = m['Text']
sql = """INSERT INTO posts(nmbr, msg, tel, sts) \
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"""
values = (number, risk, 'smart', 'u')
cur.execute(sql,values)  #use comma to separate sql and values, this will ensure values are escaped/sanitized
cur.commit()
```

now you dont need these two lines:

```
msg = risk.encode('utf8')
text = db.escape_string(msg)
```

Comment: _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'\'\', \'\'Lala*=#&%@<>_?!:;-\\\\\\\'\\\\\\"/()\xc2\xa5\xc2\xa1\xc2\xbf\'\', \'\'smart\'\', \'\'u\'\')\' at line 1')

Comment: @weyhei sorry try the `sql` again, i've edited it (i've removed the apostrophes surrounding the %s )

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear whether your `m['Text']` value is of type `StringType` or `UnicodeType`.  My bet is that it is a byte-string (`StringType`).  If that's true, then adding a line `m['Text'] = m['Text'].decode('UTF-8')` before your insert may work.

Comment: I print out the array m and text is:  ***'Text': u'Lala*=#&%@<>_?!:;-\'"/()\xa5\xa1\xbf'***